# Usar LinkedInOpenIdProvider con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, socialite

tengo instalado
Laravel 10.10
Laravel breeze 1.13
Laravel socialite 5.9

Quiero hacer Login con Linkedin

return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();

Pero Linkedin ya dejo de dar soporte a los scope r_liteprofile y r_emailaddress

deseo usar LinkedInOpenIdProvider.php pero no me deja seleccionar este provider al usarlo de la siguiente manera

return Socialite::driver('linkedinopenid')->redirect();

alguien ha logrado usar este provider?

Answer (score 1):

ya encontre la respuesta para usarlo

es con el siguiente comando

return Socialite::driver('linkedin-openid')->redirect();